# Django: problems while loading custom filters in the base template file while using template inheritance

Tags: django, django-templates, django-1.4, django-template-filters

When doing the `{% load custom_filters %}` in the template, after `{% extends "base.html" %}` everything works fine, but when I move the load to the base.html template the filter gets a weird behaviour. This is my `custom_filters.py`:

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

# To cut off strings at a specified character, at first occurance. Example:
#   time = 19:30:12.123456
#   {{ time|cut:'.' }}
#   returns: 19:30:12
@register.filter
@stringfilter
def cut(string, cutoff_point):
    return string.split(cutoff_point, 1)[0]
```

When I load it in the 'end-template' the behaviour is as expected. If `time = 19:30:12.123456` then `{{ time|cut:'.' }}` returns `19:30:12`. When I load it in `base.html` the returned value is `19:30:12123456`, the same as the input but without the 'cutoff-point'.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Great question. Save me hours of time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should place `{% load ... %}` in every template, where you want to use your custom tag or filter.

In your case it's also not a good idea to call a filter `cut`, because this filter [already exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#cut) (and it's used to cut a dot from your string).

Comment: Oh, I must have missed that. That explains why it did the strange behaviour. But there's got to be a way to do the load in the base template, that's the idea of including/inheritance - not to have to write the same piece of code in 100 places.

Comment: @olofom It is how [Django works](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#custom-libraries-and-template-inheritance). But you can use one [nice undocumented trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184983/load-a-django-template-tag-library-for-all-views-by-default). And take a good look at Carl Meyer's comment.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Well then, I should just load it in every template then after all. Thanks!

Comment: load 3 dots? or load what?